# Jenkinsfile unable to run docker with multiple params

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkinsfile I have this

```
    stage ('Build Docker') {
        steps {
            script {
                image1 = docker.build "docker1:${BRANCH_NAME}"
            }

            script {
                image2 = docker.build "docker2:${BRANCH_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }

    stage ('Run Docker Acceptance Tests') {
        steps {

                script {
                    container1 = image1.run "-v /tmp/${BRANCH_NAME}:/var/lib/data"
                    container1Id = container1.id

                    container1IP = sh script: "docker inspect ${container1Id} | grep IPAddress | grep -v null| cut -d \'\"\' -f 4 | head -1", returnStdout: true
                }

                //let containers start up
                sleep 20

                script {
                    container2= image2.run("-v /tmp/${BRANCH_NAME}:/var/lib/data --add-host=MY_HOST:${container1IP}")
                }

            }
        }
```

When it gets to run container2 I get this output.

```
[resources] Running shell script
00:01:33.775 + docker run -d -v /tmp/master:/var/lib/data --add-host=MY_HOST:172.17.0.3
00:01:33.775 "docker run" requires at least 1 argument(s).
00:01:33.775 See 'docker run --help'.
```

Clearly its not appending the container name when running the docker image.

I tried just hardcoding in the IP address to test if it worked like this

```
container2= image2.run("-v /tmp/${BRANCH_NAME}:/var/lib/data --add-host=MY_HOST:172.17.0.3")
```

And then it worked and ran the command correctly

```
00:00:29.386 [resources] Running shell script
00:00:29.641 + docker run -d -v /tmp/master:/var/lib/data --add-host=MY_HOST:172.17.0.3 docker-name:branch
```

I dont understand why its not picking up the container image name.

I have even tried doing this - getting the same error

```
container2= image2.run("-v /tmp/${BRANCH_NAME}:/var/lib/data --add-host=MY_HOST:${container1IP} docker2:${BRANCH_NAME}")
```

My final step I tried

```
sh "docker run -v /tmp/${BRANCH_NAME}:/var/lib/data --add-host=MY_HOST:${container1IP} docker2:${BRANCH_NAME}"
```

Again it seems like it is stripping off the final command after resolving ${container1IP}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

managed to fix it, it was due to a hidden new line char

```
container1IP = sh (script: "docker inspect ${container1Id} | grep IPAddress | grep -v null| cut -d \'\"\' -f 4 | head -1", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Trimming the var fixed it